# the receiver does not show the message. BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver

**Hello everyone, I'm new to programming. When I press the button, nothing happens, I can't find the error. Please see. On assignment, I need to create a message listener (Receiver) and send text data to it by clicking on a button. Show the received data in Toast. .xml file:
**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/btn_send_message"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
    
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**.kt file:**

package kg.tutorialapp.homework_47

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private val myAction = "kg.tutorialapp.action.MESSAGE"
private val alarmMessage = "Hello world!"

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
    button.setOnClickListener { sendMessage() }

}

private fun sendMessage() {
    val intent = Intent()
    intent.action = myAction
    intent.putExtra("kg.tutorialapp.broadcast.MESSAGE", alarmMessage)
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES)
    sendBroadcast(intent)
}
```

}

**receiver file:**

```
        class Receiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    
        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
    
            Toast.makeText(context, "Новое сообщение: " + intent.getStringExtra("kg.tutorialapp.broadcast.MESSAGE"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
```

**> manifest:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        package="kg.tutorialapp.homework_47">
    
        <application
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Homework_47"
            tools:ignore="AllowBackup">
            <receiver
                android:name=".Receiver"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:exported="true"
                tools:ignore="ExportedReceiver">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="kg.tutorialapp.action.MESSAGE"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
    
            <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>
    
    </manifest>
```

Comment: in your `BroadcastReceiver` you are trying to get `String` under `"kg.tutorialapp.broadcast.Message"` key - thats not the key you are setting, as it have `MESSAGE` - big cases - as a last part

Comment: so I'm adding this as an answer :) good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try `removing android:permission="TODO"` from your reciever's manifest declaration.

Refer [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#restrict-broadcasts-permissions)

Comment: thank you, I removed permission, but also nothing happens when clicked